# What Is the Procedure and Guidelines for Moving Comments on a Question to Meta?  Is It Necessary?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, moderator-tools

On some of the beta sites, such as [Project Management Stack Exchange](http://pm.stackexchange.com), some of the questions accumulate a series of comments related to the on/off-topic nature of the question.

[One question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/what-criteria-should-be-considered-when-deciding-to-do-work-which-goes-beyond-pro) has 10 comments discussing why the question was closed by a moderator, what was done to fix those problems, and requests to reopen the question.

After the edits, the question was reopened.

Should the comments be moved to the site meta or should the comments be left as a signpost for other users to help convey the metamorphosis from a bad, subjective rant to a good, subjective question?

If the comments should be moved, how does one accomplish that?  Can regular users move comments?  Can a moderator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no widely common procedure or guideline for moving the *actual* comments from the main site into a Meta discussion. It varie a lot between sites, some sites preserve a lot of comment streams while others only preserve some of the particularly noteworthy ones. Some put it in chat and link the transcript, others post into a post body.

There is no actual "move" functionality. In terms of simplicity, the best option is traditionally a whole-sale copy/paste of the comment thread into an appropriate medium, then the moderator "Delete Comments" ability to clear the thread. You'll need a moderator to accomplish the latter, but a normal user could always do the first part and then flag for the second.

As far as when to do it, it depends a lot on the nature of the comment exchange. Generally, Meta discussion (or a move to chat) is sprung when things are no longer suited to sticking in comments. This often comes up because:

- The comments are getting too heated
- The comments are straying away from the content of the post they are attached to
- The comments are numerous in quantity
- It is a reasonable expectation that one of the above is going to happen if nothing is done

In general, preserving the comments in the Meta discussion is only necessary *if you're getting rid of the comments on the Main site*, and *only if the comments are worth preserving*. For example, if it's a heated discussion, then keeping all the flames alight is probably not wise. Or, if you're just pre-empting a thick discussion, then adding a comment "This has now had a Meta discussion opened, please direct further commentary there" can let you simply leave the 10 or so comments on the post, if they're fine on their own right.

Answer (score 2):

Just clear the comments using your special mod powers.
I don't think you can move comments.
If you find anything salvageable quote it and place it into a meta question and then place a link to it on the original post.